# Check if error due to no spatial reference of extracted raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

[image]

I have raster file without spatial reference and I extracted my area of interest by shapefile that has spatial reference. Finally, I got extracted raster with spatial reference. Can I assume the raster taken the spatial reference from the shapefile during extraction process?

Comment: That would be a safe assumption. However if your input raster has no spatial reference, the area of overlap between the shape file and the raster is... well, not quite random, but it doesn't mean anything either. It's just where the shape happens to overlap when placing the unknown units/origin of the input into the shape's CRS. Depending on the CRS you could get wildly different results.

Comment: In your question it is not clear to me whether your picture is of a model that you are running or just of a process similar to what you are doing.  Can you **edit** your question to make clear what you are doing, what you are observing (e.g. error messages), and where you are stuck, please?  I would not assume, I would check the coordinate systems of all input and output datasets.